# How to connect substrate node to metamask?

Tags: rust, evm, ethereum, metamask

My node is compatible with EVM and I would like to connect it to metamask?

How can I do it?
What should I put in RPC URL and chain id? (Where can I find my chain id)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP RPC url is what you want, which is what you see at the beginning of the logs. By default this is localhost and port 9933, but you can change this with the flag `--rpc-port`
[image]

In terms of chainId, if you just want to connect to it, you can just enter whatever you like and it'll publish what ChainId is detected at that address:

[image]

However if you are interested on where this is derived, it depends on your implementation. e.g. for moonbeam: https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/blob/6d7206efed3892e8a371666104c33b3113b57eaa/runtime/moonbeam/src/lib.rs#L237

and here for astar:
https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/blob/5d58da413005db8e61a53673507c0e502e22e646/runtime/astar/src/lib.rs#L683

---

Note: If you are trying to connect your metamask to a node not on the same machine, you'll need to use the flag `--rpc-external` to accept connections from a different IP.

Comment: Were you able to add your network manually? I was NOT able because of this chain id issue :/ The save button does not work. Can you please tell me how did you do it?

Comment: did you choose the chain id suggested in the message (in the case above it's 1281, not 2) ?

Comment: To add on to this, when you customize to a new ChainID, please check if it has already been taken. A good place to check on is https://chainlist.org/